# Printing Runtime exec() OutputStream to console

Tags: java, stream, runtime, runtime.exec, printstream

I am trying to get the `OutputStream` of the `Process` initiated by `exec()` to the console. How can this be done?

Here is some incomplete code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Reader;

public class RuntimeTests
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File path = new File("C:\\Dir\\Dir2");
        String command = "cmd /c dir";
        Reader rdr = null;
        PrintStream prtStrm = System.out;
        try
        {
            Runtime terminal = Runtime.getRuntime();

            OutputStream rtm = terminal.exec(command, null, path).getOutputStream();
            prtStrm = new PrintStream(rtm);
            prtStrm.println();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Benjamin Gruenbaum answer covering ProcessBuilder API available since Java 7.

You need to start a new thread that would read process output happening after `Process.waitFor()`. Then process output can be copied the console from that thread.

`Process.getOutputStream()` is actually the input, ie, stdin to the process.  `Process.getInputStream()` and `Process.getErrorStream()` return `InputStream` objects which are the stdout and stderr of the process.  The `InputStream`s and `OutputStream` are from the caller's perspective, which is the opposite of the process's perspective.

The process's output, stdout, is input to the caller, therefore the caller gets a `getInputStream()` and reads the stdout from it:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArr, env, cwdir);

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
while((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) { 
  System.out.println(line);
} 

isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream());
rdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
while((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) { 
  System.out.println(line);
} 
rc = proc.waitFor();  // Wait for the process to complete
```

`Process.getOutputStream()` is used for the caller to 'output' data into the stdin of the process.  This code could be added after 'proc' is created in the first line of the example above, to send data into stdin of the process:

```
// Send data to stdin of the process (in development, needs input content)
OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
Bytes content = new Bytes("Hello\nasdf\n adma");
os.write(content.arr, content.off, content.length());
os.close(); // should use try/finally or try/resource
```

Do the above before reading the output. Remember to close the `OutputStream` os (either using try/resource or try/finally). So, the process knows that stdin is complete and it can finish processing the info.

Comment: For everyone coming to this question nowadays: scroll down, there's a better answer below

Comment: (The answer was edited to be a better answer again.)

Answer (score 118):

I recently ran into this problem and just wanted to mention that since java 7 the [process builder api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28%29) has been expanded. This problem can now be solved with:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("yourcommand");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Perfect and elegant answer. If you can use Java 7, this is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: This is the best answer, even though there are good ones above, always try to use the tools that come in the Java toolbox by default. Java 7/8 is an extremely capable and powerful language - with an ever expanding, yet efficient, toolkit.

Comment: I get the following error message with Java 11: "Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1." Is it possible that this solution does not longer work with Java 11?

Comment: Thanks! `pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);` solved a lot of weird quircks for me which was lacking from most other examples online

Comment: @BitfulByte happy to have helped, this was literally my first coding task for TipRanks!

Answer (score 46):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
  String line;
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  input.close();
```

Comment: I have a question to your solution: Is there no need to use process.waitFor()? It works also without but why? Does the InputStreamReader wait until the stream ends?

Comment: Yes, API: _If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown._

Comment: add a `redirectErrorStream(true)` for completeness.

Comment: why inputStream? we're interested in the output, aren't we?

Answer (score 13):

I faced the similar problem and I am using the following code.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(".....");
p.waitFor();

String line;

BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
while((line = error.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
error.close();

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while((line=input.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}

input.close();

OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
printStream.println();
printStream.flush();
printStream.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old question, but a better alternate for the above answers would be

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.inheritIO();
Process p = builder.start();
```

From the docs of `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`,

> Sets the source and destination for subprocess standard I/O to be the
>   same as those of the current Java process.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Try [`VerboseProcess`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/apidocs-0.7.5/com/jcabi/log/VerboseProcess.html) from [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/threads-VerboseProcess.html):

```
String output = new VerboseProcess(new ProcessBuilder("foo.bat")).stdout();
```

The class starts a background thread, listens to the output stream, and logs it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use org.apache.commons.io.IOUTils from commons-io,

```
System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(process.getInputStream()));
System.err.println(IOUtils.toString(process.getErrorStream()));
```