# XML response causing freeze in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jsoup

This could is designed to send a request to a server in XML and get a response in XML. It causes the system to freeze

```
if (!jTextField9.getText().equals("")){
    String reportID = jTextField9.getText();
    try{
    // Report pull code    //"cmd /c omp -u admin -w admin --xml=\"<start_task task_id='" + taskId + "'/>\"";
                     final String dosCommand = "cmd /c omp -u admin -w admin --xml=\"<get_reports report_id='" + reportID + "' format_id='a3810a62-1f62-11e1-9219-406186ea4fc5'/>\"";
                   final String location = "C:\\";
try {
 final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    dosCommand + " " + location);
 final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
 int ch;
 while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)ch);
```

If you need more info please let me know

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Runtime exec() OutputStream to console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console)

Comment: This seemed to sort it - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the external process and read it in another thread, not in the main one. Something like the following:

```
new Thread(){

  public void run(){
             final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dosCommand + " " + location);
             final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

             int ch;
             while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)ch);
                /* ... etc */
             }

  }

}.start();
```

If you don't open a new thread, the main thread (which also draws your graphical components) have to wait the remote response.

Comment: Thank you this is most helpful