# Java program to execute a command taking a long time

Tags: java, optimization, command-line

I have read many examples and ended up using the following code to execute a command line command from inside of a Java program.

```
public static void executeCommand(final String command) throws IOException, 
    InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Executing command " + command);
        final Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final Process p = r.exec(command);
        System.out.println("waiting for the process");
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("waiting done");
        try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;

            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tested it with a simple ls command and it works fine. When I try to run another command, it is taking forever (kept running for 25 minutes and did not stop yet).

When I execute a tabix command on the command line, I get the following statistics

> 4.173u 0.012s 0:04.22 99.0%     0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w

Hence it should finish fast.

The command is

> time tabix file pos1 pos2 ... pos190 > /dev/null

Could the problem be that the tabix command includes `> /dev/null` at the end? If not, what could cause this issue?

Comment: What is "forever"? Have you tried other commands, both simple and difficult? There probably is an extra delay depending on what is in the command.

Comment: More details, please. What is the exact command you're running? What are the timings for running the command directly, and what are the timings for a `public static void main` that just executes this command and then terminates?

Comment: The command has been running for 14 minutes and is still running.

Comment: the command is basically time tabix file pos1 pos2 pos3 ... pos190 > /dev/null

Comment: I've had a similar problem with an execution with parameters, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25082093/869783

Comment: what if I am not allowed to run sudo?

Comment: You need to attach the reader to the process **before** calling it's `waitFor`. Without that it will fill it's allocated output buffer and then block - but only for big output, small output will seem to be fine.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon thank you! that had fixed it! One more question - why is the redirection to dev/null still displayed?

Comment: @tad - what does it print - there should be a hint there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the reader to the process **before** calling it's `waitFor`. Without that it *could* fill it's allocated output buffer and then block - but only for big output, small (e.g. test) output will seem to be fine.

```
public static void executeCommand(final String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Executing command " + command);
    // Make me a Runtime.
    final Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // Start the command process.
    final Process p = r.exec(command);
    // Pipe it's output to System.out.
    try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    // Do this AFTER you've piped all the output from the process to System.out
    System.out.println("waiting for the process");
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("waiting done");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me!