# Java doesn't print out shell echo

Tags: java, shell, output, echo

I'm running a shell script using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Everything works fine, exept for the output. So, this script

```
echo "opening gedit..."
gedit
```

Opens gedit, but when running from Java I don't get any output. What is the problem?

Comment: Where do you expect to see the output and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Runtime exec() OutputStream to console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console)

Answer (score 0):

```
 String line;
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  input.close();
```

As mentioned in [Printing Runtime exec() OutputStream to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console)