# I am not able to get expected output from run time exec

Tags: java

I executed this code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /home/uhf/metrics.sh");
System.out.println(proc.toString());
String proc1 = proc.toString();
```

But I am not able to get the content of kafka_metrics.sh. Instead I am getting `java.lang.UNIXProcess@5fd0d5ae` as output. What should I include so that I can get the content of that file?

Comment: are you aware what does this do: ***System.out.println(proc.toString());*** ??

Comment: Can you read the file with pure Java? Because I would prefer that, and calling `toString` on your `Process` is not what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console

Comment: becasue you make the command ``toString``?

Comment: I think it is changing the output to string and used to display the output.

Comment: So what should I do to get the output to be displayed

Comment: how to use pure java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this is what you are looking for.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /home/uhf/metrics.sh");
String s = null;
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

// read the output from the command
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
}

// read any errors from the attempted command
System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i have updated my code. I mistakenly wrote p instead of proc while initializing the two BufferedReader objects.

Comment: System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
          while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(s);
                  String s1 = s;
          }
          
          System.out.println("String read------->"+stdInput.readLine());
          String s1 = stdInput.readLine();                                                                             I wrote this code but whenever it comes out of while string is losing it's value so to get that same what should I do. I mean I am getting null value but I want the content of file.

Comment: Content of file means the content of metrics.sh? In that case you can directly read that file. The piece of example i provided will give you the output of the command that you are executing through Java's Runtime, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the Process object.

to get the content of the executed process you need to take the input stream and pass that stream to the reader

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /home/uhf/metrics.sh");
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```