# Got IOException CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, eclipse, processbuilder

I am new to `ProcessBuilder`. Today I am writing a simple application to execute the "java -version" but always got the `IOException`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java -version");
        try {
            Map<String, String> map = pb.environment();  
            Process p  = pb.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The exception thrown as below

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -version": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

I can ensure that `JAVA_HOME` is set in environment variable, my eclipse is pointing to the jdk too.

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\JDK1.8.0_66-X64.
```

Can anyone tell what the problem is in my code/settings ?

Comment: You need to pass `"java"` and `"-version"` as separate command arguments when you're constructing the `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: ProcessBuilder takes the first element of array and interprets it as the program(command) name and rest of all as arguments to the program. Try ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"java", "-version"});

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia There is a varargs constructor so you don't need to manually create the array

Comment: @JonK right and sure it is!! Actually I am habitual of firing long commands so used to pass array over there.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the class `ProcessBuilder` you are using takes an argument of type `String...`. Also the first element of this must be the name of the operating system program alone. You are getting this exception since the system could not find file named `java -version.exe`(if you are in Windows). The file name you want is `java.exe` So use `ProcessBuilder("java", "-version")`. See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). There is a nice example in the documentation.

Comment: Thx. By splitting the command into two parts the program runs with no exception. But I can't find there is any output by checking the p.getInputStream() right after pb.start().  I am following the approach here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console

Comment: I have figured it out . Need to append inheritIO() for pb