# Run python from java with an argument

Tags: java, python

This is my java code. with the script quest.py i want that file.txt to execute from java. but not working. pleaseee help. i am stuck here

```
String command = "python C:/KDU/genquest-master/quest.py file.txt";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command );
```

Comment: *not working* is not an error description. Can you explain in Detail. BTW Read the error stream to find out what is happening

Comment: @Jens no error occuring.  seriously. thats why i am stuck

Comment: I am sure there is an error. You can see it if you read the error stream I guess pyhthon is not in the path or something like that

Comment: but it works in cmd tho :/

Comment: Maybe it works on cmd. You run it in the same Directory? with the same user?

Comment: I suggest you use the following code ["Printing Runtime exec() OutputStream to console"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console) to print out the output of your python process to the console, this gives an error that you can then use to improve your question

Comment: @jens yes with the same user and the directory is same

Comment: Have you tried to reat the error strem and took a look if you get any message?

Answer (score 1):

your problem in python input file.txt you should add complete path of file for python input

```
String command = "python C:/KDU/genquest-master/quest.py C:/KDU/genquest-master/file.txt";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command );
```